# Disable Timezones in User Account

Tags: 7, users

How do you disable Timezone from being edited in a User account? Is there a config setting I can turn off?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Visit `index.php?q=admin/config/regional/settings` to configure whether users are able to set their own timezone.